# Displaying long ntext field in PHP page has truncated or strange text appended

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a problem trying to display an ntext MS SQL Server field in my PHP web page.

The field in the database stores an HTML formatted document with all the tags.

Database MS SQL 2012 with collation set to `Latin1_General_CI_AS` and the field type is `ntext`

HTML page has an encoding meta tag set to UTF8

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

PHP has the following to try to strip out the tags.

```
$note2 = odbc_result($result, data2);
$note2 = mb_convert_encoding($note2, 'UTF-8', 'Latin1_General_CI_AS');
$note2 = strip_tags($note2, "<br><p>");
echo trim($note2);
```

I am getting strange and inconsistent results 
For example the second half of the actual text is replaced with some other text that can include SQL code or warning messages like this.

> functitrto¸Ù 4¬T 4¬T  not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. Plep! ì«T ì«T .timezone setting, the TÙì èÕì ment variable
>   oe date_d fault_timezone_set() function. In c àYì Ùì ù 0 Days, 1
>   Hours, 16 Minsll getting thisøÁ t¬T t¬T st likely misspelled the
>   timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for '1.0/DST'
>   instead0ù¬«T ¬«T É0  ±± Üì  L{  ÈNì  ~üa´ÐÜì    Câ É

I have tried `CAST(myntextfield AS TEXT) AS mytextfield` but that changed my returned text so that it only returned the second half of the message, so that was no good.

The problem occurs 4000ish characters into the text, I do not know if that is significant. I have set the two values, `mssql.textlimit` and `mssql.textsize` to 65000 in the php.ini file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the answer, I needed to set the `odbc.defaultlrl` value in the php.ini file, my database connection is an ODBC one.